# Creating a struct of callbacks in LuaJIT FFI

Tags: c, dll, lua, ffi, luajit

So first I load in a DLL I need

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
local theDLL = ffi.load("thisDLL")
```

in the ffi cdef I have this struct

```
ffi.cdef [[
    typedef struct {
        /*
        * begin_proj callback
        */
        bool (__cdecl *begin_proj)(char *proj);

        /*
        * save_proj_state
        */
        bool (__cdecl *save_proj_state)(unsigned char **buffer, int *len);
    } StructCallbacks;
```

I also have this function in the cdef

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl start_session(StructCallbacks *cb);
```

Now I would like to call this function

```
print(theDLL.start_session(myCallbacks))
```

the question is how can I pass the structs the function needs (how do I make myCallbacks a struct of callbacks to Lua functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the struct and assign the fields to Lua functions, as you would with any other value.

```
local callbacks = ffi.new("StructCallbacks")

callbacks.begin_proj = function(proj) return false end
callbacks.save_proj_state = function(buffer, len) return true end
```

See the [FFI callback docs](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html#callback) for more in-depth information on callbacks.